# Start Docker Desktop and a Docker stack from a batch file (Windows)

Tags: batch-file, docker-for-windows

How can I start both the Docker service, a Docker Swarm and the Docker Desktop from a Windows batch file?

I created all kinds of variants, for example:

```
@echo off
echo "[1] Start Docker Desktop ... "
start /B "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe"
echo "[2] Waiting for Docker to accept commands ... "
timeout /t 20
:repeat
docker ps -a >> output.txt || ( timeout /t 10 && goto :repeat; )
echo " ... Docker started ... "
timeout /t 5
echo "[3] Starting a Docker Stack (Swarm) ... "
cd \a-docker-compose-folder
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml devhome
echo " ... Docker Swarm started ... "
```

When I don't use the "start /B" the batch file is starting the Desktop (and service) but is waiting for ever. So, it will not start (of course) the next commands.

Another option is to start the docker service, but I could not find dockerd.exe. Then starting the Docker Swarm ... and finally the Docker Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple to accomplish this:

1. Create one file, in this case 'docker-polling-start-postgres-swarm.bat', for polling and starting ...

> ```
> @echo off
> echo "[1] Starting a Docker Swarm with Postgres ... "
> :repeat
> docker ps -a > output.txt || ( timeout /t 5 && goto :repeat; )
> echo " ... Docker started ... "
> timeout /t 5
> echo "[2] Starting a Docker Swarm with Postgres ... "
> docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml devhome
> echo " ... Docker Swarm started ... "
> ```

2. Create the main batch file to FIRST start the above file in the background and THEN start the Docker Desktop in the foreground. You will still see exactly what is happing in your batch file output!

> ```
> @echo off
> echo "[1] Start-and-poll Docker Swarm in the background till it can be started... "
> start /B docker-polling-start-postgres-swarm.bat
> echo "[2] Start Docker EE in the background ... "
> "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe"
> set /p id="Finish"
> ```

I created a simple quick link on the desktop. Just clicking on the quick link starts all. Enjoy!